# Получить координаты точки при клике мышью по графику?

Tags: c#, winforms

как получить координату X при нажатии на график в c#, компонента Chart.

Comment: WinForm или WPF?

Comment: WinForm  приложение

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Метод **[Chart.HitTest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.hittest(v=vs.110).aspx)** вам в помощь.

Определяет элемент диаграммы, если таковой существует, расположенный в точке, которая определяется заданными координатами X и Y. Более подробно в официальной документации по ссылке выше.

Ну и для демонстрации, вот вам обработчик возвращающий значение Y точки, в которую кликнули.

```
private void chart1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var res = chart1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
    if(res.Series != null)
        MessageBox.Show(res.Series.Points[res.PointIndex].YValues[0].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Событие `MouseClick` свойство `e.X`

Comment: Получит координаты курсора относительно левой стороны компонента Chart, но не координаты точки на графике

Comment: @slippyk, так ТС и не говорил, что надо координату на графике.

Comment: нужна именно координата на графике